# how line break with JSPDF

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have a project in react, and I have a long column and I would like to know how to break and repeat the first 3 columns.
The table is dynamic, it does not have a fixed size.
[Image Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEzMu.png)

```
    doc.autoTable({
        head: [this.state.headerRelatorio.map(element => element)],
            headerStyles: {
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: [0, 0, 0]
        },body : this.state.body.map(element=> this.state.headerRelatorio.map(elem => {if(element[elem] === undefined){
            return 0
        }else{
            return element[elem];
        }
    }
        )),
        overflow: 'linebreak',
            styles: {
                font: 'arial',
                fontsize:8,
                minCellWidth: 70,
                minCellHeight: 20,
                maxCellwidth:30,
                halign: 'center',
                valign:'middle',
                border: 1,
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: [0, 0, 0],
                overflow: 'linebreak'
                
            },
        theme:'grid',
        startY: 150,
        })
```

Comment: [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) read this to improve your question, also do not use images and introduce the code to understand what you are doing